# Bug fixing practices

Tags: debugging

Hey guys do any of you who are professional developers have any process for bug fixing, like whoever wrote the buggy code has to fix it, or more specifically if you hire someone new to fix your bugs. Do you just hand them 10 000 lines of code in 200 files and tell them about the bug or you have some sort of design documents(maybe so they have an idea what the 90 different classes do?) or perhaps provide some sort of architecture document.

I'm a newbie working as a professional so I don't really know how it works or should work, can someone with more experience help.

Comment: The question is too wide, voting for close.

Comment: The coder of the buggy code should fix it, and have the fixed properly reviewed and retested by someone else.

Comment: BTW, if you only have 90 classes, you're very lucky...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can write a book in order to try answer your question. It is very wide and hard to answer in 1-2 sentences. There are a lot of situations, methodologies and so on.

Answer (score 1):

1. Write a test/tests, that would pass without bug.
2. Fix bug.
3. Make sure tests pass.

Repeat.

(That's in theory: despite best intentions and deadlines, it rarely happens that way)

Other things that help are:

1. Continuous Integration (CI) build.
2. Unit Tests
3. Smoke tests
4. Integration tests

Steve McConnell's book "[Rapid Development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapid_application_development)" though not recent is worth reading.

Documentation isn't always that useful as it has a tendency to be out of date and out of sync with the code, especially in 'bug fixing, get this out the door mode'